# Is there a possibility to have search bar in plot generated by ggplot/plotly?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization, plotly

I would like to know is there any possibility that I can add `search bar` as can be done by [**clickme**](http://rclickme.com/) rpackage 
in my `ggplot` or `plotly`?

For instance using the `mtcars` data sets and `ggplot2` package:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, col= cyl, size= cyl)) +geom_point()
```

[image]

**Question:** 
Can I have a search bar (**shown by the green arrow**) like the one that can be seen below which is generated by [**clickme**](http://rclickme.com/) rpackage?

[image]
**Expected plot:** 
The expected graph would be the `ggplot` as first graph with a `search bar` which I can search the car name of my interest in the graph.

Comment: Could a shiny app be a solution for you or does it need to be independent of a running R server?

Comment: @nevrome.  I really do not want to be greedy but is it possible for you please to explain both OR either of those options which is possible ?

Comment: Ok - you could easily get a plot with a search field if you would set up a [shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) like for example [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html) one. Unfortunately this solution requires a running shiny server in the background. Plotly on the other hand produces an independent html script which does a limited set of stuff with javascript. No need for a server.

Comment: @nevrome. tnx for the help !

Comment: So.... is a shiny app a solution for you?

Comment: @nevrome, honestly not really! But based on my research I think currently there is nothing available yet that I am looking for. specially when I do not want to use a server and just looking for an html page to use. if you know any package or a coding that I can use to with ggplot or plotly would highly apprecite to share.